# Infinite intersection of empty collection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Munkres suggests that we can definite the infinite intersection of an empty collection $\mathcal{A}$ of sets as
$$\bigcap\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A = \mathcal{U},$$
where $\mathcal{U}$ is the entire set-theoretic universe. This means sense intuitively, since every $x \in \mathcal{U}$ trivially lives in every $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

On the flip side, for some set $B$, we consider
$$\bigcap\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} (B-A),$$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is still the empty collection. I am trying to frame the argument purely in terms of set differences rather than compliments, using the notation in Munkres. If I didn't do that, I would write
$$\bigcap\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} (B - A) = \bigcap\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} B \cap A^c,$$
but $A^c$ doesn't make much sense since $\mathcal{A}$ is the empty collection. If $A$ lives in $\mathcal{A}$, isn't $A$ the empty set? The complement of the empty set is $\mathcal{U}$, the whole universe, and so $B \cap A^c = B \cap \mathcal{U} = B$. The intersection of $B$ with itself an arbitrary number of times is $B$. This is the result I was looking for, but I don't think the process is completely correct.

Comment: Whether or not it is "completely correct", it is a useful convention.

Comment: Is the convention that if $\mathcal{A}$ is the empty collection, any $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is the empty set? (Just to be sure I'm understanding.)

Comment: I assume that we can trivially say that $x \in A$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$ in the same way that we may say that $x \not \in A$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$, so  we can conclude immediately that $\bigcap\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} (B - A) = B$. Is this correct?

Comment: By the **definition** of the empty set, there is no $A\in\emptyset$.

Comment: This makes sense. So does the above set equivalence I just mentioned just follow from the implication being vacuously true? (The antecedent ``if $A \in \mathcal{A}'$' is false if $\mathcal{A}$ is the empty collection.)

Comment: Yes: $a\in A$ for all $A\in\emptyset$ is vacuously true.

Comment: My apologies: are we saying that $\mathcal{A} = \emptyset$? I am not sure if I understand your last comment.

Comment: **You** said "if $\mathcal A$ is the empty collection".

Comment: Yes, but I think I am confused as to the distinction between the empty collection and the empty set. Is an empty collection an empty set?

Comment: An empty collection is a collection that is empty. On page 12, a collection is defined to be a set that consists of sets. Being empty implies the collection has no sets, and by definition, the collection can't have any other elements than sets. So the collection has no elements, which means it is the empty set. For example, $A=\{1,2,...\},B=\{1,2,\{a\},...\},C=\{\{a\},\{b\},...\}$. $A,B$ are sets, $C$ is a collection. This is what I understood from the set theory in the text but in axiomatic set theory, everything is a set and 'set' and 'collection' defined above are the same.

Answer (score 1):

x in $\cap$empty collection iff
for all K in empty collection x in K iff
True.

Explanation of the last step.
If K in empty collection, then the contradiction empty collection is not empty.
Thus False has been derived.
Where upon prove x in K by contradiction.
If x not in K, then False as shown above.
By contradiction, conclude x in K.

Such is the wonderous mysteries of material implication, that False implies True.

Your set difference calculations are superfluous because in both cases the collection is empty.